# URL not matching any url pattern in Django

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django by trying to create a blog. I wanted to add a comment section in the blog post. Now I am getting a no match error with the regex I used in my URL Pattern when I click submit in my comment form. But when I try the regex on pythex it seems to match the resultant url that gets redirected after I click the submit button.
This is my HTML form:

```
    <form id ="post_form" method = "post" action = "add_comment/">

  {{ commentform | as_bootstrap }}

  <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Create Comment">
```

This is the URL pattern:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from blog import views

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
        url(r'^add_post/', views.add_post, name = 'add_post'),
        url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w|\-]+)/$', views.post, name = 'post'),
        url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w|\-]+])/add_comment/$', views.add_comment, name = 'add_comment')
    ]
```

This is the error message on django:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/blog/title-3/add_comment/
Using the URLconf defined in bloggy_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^blog/ ^$ [name='index']
^blog/ ^add_post/ [name='add_post']
^blog/ ^(?P<slug>[\w|\-]+)/$ [name='post']
^blog/ ^(?P<slug>[\w|\-]+])/add_comment/$ [name='add_comment']
^media/(?P<path>.*)$

The current URL, blog/title-3/add_comment/, didn't match any of these.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

I tried different combinations since I am new to regex but I am not able to get it to work.

Comment: There is an extra closing square bracket (`]`) at the last `url`. You should remove that.

Comment: Thanks a lot - that fixed it. I slammed my head hard after seeing the mistake I made.